# Why did the new high school have a dirt floor in Buffy Season 7?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

In Buffy Season 7, Xander rebuilds the high school with a dirt floor in the basement for convenient access to the Hellmouth. Wouldn't a concrete foundation be more traditional than dirt? Also, pouring concrete over the Hellmouth seems like a good way to stop blood getting on it and releasing Turok-Han super-vampires...

Why wasn't the high school rebuilt with a concrete foundation in the basement?

Comment: Like all good contractors, he's learning to cut corners.

Comment: @Radhil - Quite the opposite. He was using undue influence to massively overbuild the floor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The First Evil](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/The_First_Evil) was deliberately confusing the construction crews with a mixture of illusions and magic:

> INT. HIGH SCHOOL BASEMENT - DAY
>
> Xander and Buffy make their way through the maze of the basement.
>
> **XANDER:** *You can't use the blueprints to find your way around, down
> here. Seems like the walls move or something...*
>
> <sub><sup>[Buffy: Same Time, Same Place](http://www.buffyworld.com/buffy/scripts/125_scri.html)</sup></sub>

Note that Xander did indeed attempt to use his influence (as Senior Contractor) to have the Hellmouth covered in tons and tons of cement, but apparently he missed.

> **Xander:** *I got two crews working this diabolical yet lucrative new campus:
> finishing up the science building here, and reinforcing the gym. No
> pentagrams, no secret passageways... everything up to code and safe as
> houses. I've looked through all the plans, I've been on site after
> hours...*
>
> <sub><sup>[Buffy: Lessons](http://www.buffyworld.com/buffy/scripts/123_scri.html)</sup></sub>